# How do I execute RSpec on Cloud9

Tags: rspec, cloud9-ide

every time i try to run `rake spec` or `bundle exec rspec spec` i get an  `Permission denied - bind(2)` error.
trace:

```
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb ./spec/models/user_spec.rb 
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/ruby/drb/drb.rb:861:in `initialize': Permission denied - bind(2) (Errno::EACCES) 
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/ruby/drb/drb.rb:861:in `open' 
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/ruby/drb/drb.rb:861:in `open_server' 
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/ruby/drb/drb.rb:759:in `block in open_server' 
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/ruby/drb/drb.rb:757:in `each' 
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/ruby/drb/drb.rb:757:in `open_server' 
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/ruby/drb/drb.rb:1342:in `initialize' 
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/ruby/drb/drb.rb:1624:in `new' 
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/ruby/drb/drb.rb:1624:in `start_service' 
from /var/lib/stickshift/32aa546379f04c6dadc139307dce80f1/app-root/data/lib/ruby/gems/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/drb_command_line.rb:17:in `run' 
from /var/lib/stickshift/32aa546379f04c6dadc139307dce80f1/app-root/data/lib/ruby/gems/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:63:in `run' 
from /var/lib/stickshift/32aa546379f04c6dadc139307dce80f1/app-root/data/lib/ruby/gems/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun' 
rake aborted! 
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb ./spec/models/user_spec.rb failed 

Tasks: TOP => spec
```

is spec supported on cloud9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to run mini-test, test::unit and rspec tests on cloud9.
I think the error you are getting is either due to spork or trying to use drb (with guard or something)

I tried to get this to work as well, but I couldn't get spork to bind to $PORT, and it seems like you are not allowed to bind to any other port.

I also couldn't get guard to work properly. It would see that the files changed, but when it came to running the specs, I got errors about Unknown switches -f -r -out. Research on that pointed to bundler, and possibly needing to wrap commands in quotes before sending them out to the system. (maybe)

If you get rid of any drb or spork related stuff, I bet your tests will work.

Comment: thanks for your research! the tests are running if i remove spork/--drb/guard, but to be honest: testing without spork and guard isnt that funny. cloud9 isnt an option to use it for rails development at the moment. i'm looking forward to http://action.io which looks very good!

Comment: I was just able to get a drb server to bind, using this in irb:  
DRb::DRbServer.new("druby://#{ENV['IP']}:#{ENV['PORT']}")
So I think my earlier problem was that I wasn't giving the IP, and it was defaulting to localhost. Now if I can figure out how to tell spork the IP, and also get the guard call working...